# Why isn't my div container aligning perfectly against the section above it? There's a thin border in between the two

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGEvI.png)I'm trying to create multiple sections for this webpage layout using bootstrap. I made a section at the top for the page title and I have a div container with multiple cards. I can't figure out why there is this thin border appearing between the container and the section. Can anyone help me figure this out?

I pasted the code I'm having trouble with below in case that helps. Thanks!

Labs Team Page

```
<section>

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: lightgrey; border: none">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">

    <!--Mike's Card -->
     <div class="card m-4" style="width: 18rem;">
         <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
         <div class="card-body">
           <h5 class="card-title">Mike</h5>
           <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
           <a href="../team/mike/" class="btn btn-primary">See Mike's Page</a>
         </div>
    </div>

    <!--Carl's Card -->
    <div class="card m-4" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Carl</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="../team/carl/" class="btn btn-primary">See Carl's Page</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Aidan's Card -->
    <div class="card m-4" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Aidan</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="../team/aidan/" class="btn btn-primary">See Aidan's Page</a>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div> <!--row closing tag -->


</div> <!-- card container closing tag -->
```

Comment: add border:0 to style tag of div and see if it stil appears

Comment: I tried that earlier too, but it didn't change anything. Maybe it's not a border in that case....Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that an h1 in a section above this code did yield a gap.  That's coming from a margin-bottom on the h1 element.

Set margin-bottom to 0 on the h1 and add some padding-bottom to handle any lower case letters that drop below the line:

```
<section id="title">
<h1 style="background-color: blue; margin: 0; padding:.5rem;">Aidan's problem page</h1>
</section>

<section>

    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: lightgrey; border: none">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <!--Mike's Card -->
         <div class="card m-4" style="width: 18rem;">
             <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
             <div class="card-body">
               <h5 class="card-title">Mike</h5>
               <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
               <a href="../team/mike/" class="btn btn-primary">See Mike's Page</a>
             </div>
        </div>

        <!--Carl's Card -->
        <div class="card m-4" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Carl</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              <a href="../team/carl/" class="btn btn-primary">See Carl's Page</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Aidan's Card -->
        <div class="card m-4" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Aidan</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              <a href="../team/aidan/" class="btn btn-primary">See Aidan's Page</a>
            </div>
        </div>

      </div> <!--row closing tag -->


    </div> <!-- card container closing tag -->
</section>
```

Comment: Alternatively, wrap both sections in a `container-fluid` div so that bootstrap's styling applies to the `H1` element and add about .5rem of padding-bottom to the h1 if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much, George! It worked immediately. You're a lifesaver! 

This was bothering the crap out of me. I would've never figured that out on my own. I have so much to learn! Thanks again!

Comment: The container-fluid trick worked too, but it also made the H1 element text a lot smaller. But, it's good to know other solutions. 

One more thing, do you happen to know why the bottom container doesn't take the full height with a class of h-100 like this? 

  <div class="container-fluid h-100" style="background-color: lightgrey;border:0 ">
      <div class="row justify-content-center h-100" style=" border:0 ">

Comment: @Aidan, I'm not sure what you mean but then, I haven't worked with h-100 styling.  The docs indicate it is short-hand for max-height: 100%.  The height is based on its container and would be affected by padding-top/padding-bottom of the container.

Comment: Yeah I just started working with bootstrap, so I'm still getting used to it. I'll check out the padding of the container then. Thanks again for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

im put your code in codepen and cant see any border!?

```html
<section>

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: lightgrey; border: none">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">

    <!--Mike's Card -->
     <div class="card m-4" style="width: 18rem;">
         <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
         <div class="card-body">
           <h5 class="card-title">Mike</h5>
           <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
           <a href="../team/mike/" class="btn btn-primary">See Mike's Page</a>
         </div>
    </div>

    <!--Carl's Card -->
    <div class="card m-4" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Carl</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="../team/carl/" class="btn btn-primary">See Carl's Page</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Aidan's Card -->
    <div class="card m-4" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Aidan</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="../team/aidan/" class="btn btn-primary">See Aidan's Page</a>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div> <!--row closing tag -->


</div> <!-- card container closing tag -->
```

please send screenshot

Comment: Sorry for some reason the top part of the code was cut off. There's a border between this section and section above for the cards. 

 <section style="background-color:lightgrey; height:100%">
        <h1 class="p-5 display-3" style= "text-align: center">
          Labs Team Page
        </h1>
      </section>

Comment: I added an image to the question body. Thanks for checking so quickly Shahryar!

Comment: your welcome, add this section to and there is no border again! https://codepen.io/shahry4r/pen/eYmdGbv